# Regular expression to replace everything with a blank, except for a pattern (dplyr, stringr)

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, stringr

I have a data frame that looks like this (example data):

```
myCars <- structure(list(Engine_Information = c("Ford 3.5L 6 Cylinder 355 hp 350 ft-lbs Turbo", 
                                  "Ford 5.4L 8 cylinder 310 hp 365 ft-lbs FFV", "Audi 3.0L 6 Cylinder 333 hp 325 ft-lbs S-charged", 
                                  "Toyota 2.7L 4 Cylinder 159 hp 180 ft-lbs", "Chevrolet 4.3L 6 Cylinder 195 hp 260 ft-lbs", 
                                  "Chevrolet 3.0L 6 Cylinder 264 hp 222 ft-lbs FFV", "GMC 3.7L 5 Cylinder 242 hp 242 ft-lbs", 
                                  "Volvo 3.2 L 6 cylinder 240 hp 236 ft-lbs", "Hyundai 2.4L 4 Cylinder 198 hp 184 ft-lbs", 
                                  "Mercedes-AMG 5.4L 8 Cylinder 500 hp 516 ft-lbs S-Charged")), 
      row.names = c(1074L, 1923L, 811L, 3378L, 2419L, 2080L, 2995L, 4889L, 1023L, 1368L), 
      class = "data.frame")
```

Using `dplyr` with `stringr`, I want to create a new column which contains *only* the car's horsepower.

Here is my (attempted) code to do this:

```
myCars_HP <- myCars %>%
  mutate(HP = Engine_Information) %>%
  mutate(HP = str_replace(HP, "^(?![0-9]{3}).*$", ""))
```

The idea behind the regex pattern is to replace everything (in the new column) with blanks, *except* for the first three-digit number (this number being the HP).

However, every regex pattern I have tried just returns blanks.

My desired output would be:

[image]

I prefer to sick with `base R`/`dplyr`/`stringr` functions, so do let me know if there is a more efficient way to do this.

But above all, I would like to know why my regex isn't working, and what pattern will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the number which comes before `"hp"` string.

In base R, you can use `sub` :

```
myCars$hp <- as.numeric(sub('.*?(\\d+)\\shp.*', '\\1',myCars$Engine_Information))
```

With `dplyr`/`stringr` using positive lookahead regex.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

myCars %>%
    mutate(HP = as.numeric(str_extract(Engine_Information, '\\d+(?=\\shp)')))

#                                         Engine_Information  HP
#1              Ford 3.5L 6 Cylinder 355 hp 350 ft-lbs Turbo 355
#2                Ford 5.4L 8 cylinder 310 hp 365 ft-lbs FFV 310
#3          Audi 3.0L 6 Cylinder 333 hp 325 ft-lbs S-charged 333
#4                  Toyota 2.7L 4 Cylinder 159 hp 180 ft-lbs 159
#5               Chevrolet 4.3L 6 Cylinder 195 hp 260 ft-lbs 195
#6           Chevrolet 3.0L 6 Cylinder 264 hp 222 ft-lbs FFV 264
#7                     GMC 3.7L 5 Cylinder 242 hp 242 ft-lbs 242
#8                  Volvo 3.2 L 6 cylinder 240 hp 236 ft-lbs 240
#9                 Hyundai 2.4L 4 Cylinder 198 hp 184 ft-lbs 198
#10 Mercedes-AMG 5.4L 8 Cylinder 500 hp 516 ft-lbs S-Charged 500
```